# No logro lanzar whatsapp

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

No consigo que entre en el DependencyService desde el main para lanzar Whatsapp

Interface:

```
public interface IWhatsApp
{
    void OpenWhatsApp(StringBuilder whatsapp);
}
```

Android:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(IWhatsApp))]
namespace Proyecto
{

public class WhatsAppAndroid : IWhatsApp
{
    public void OpenWhatsApp(StringBuilder whatsapp)
    {
        Intent was = new Intent();
        was.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
        //was.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, whatsapp.ToString());
        was.SetType("text/plain");
        was.SetPackage("com.whatsapp");
        Forms.Context.StartActivity(was);
    }
}
}
```

Llamada al interface desde el main():

```
DependencyService.Get<IWhatsApp>().OpenWhatsApp(whatsapp);
```

Comment: Hola Edoman. ¿Tienes algun tipo de error o has depurado para ver qué pudo haber ido mal?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para añadir informacion a la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Ningún tipo de error. Depura perfectamente. Inserto punto de interrupción en la llamada al interface desde el main() y la salta.

Comment: Me sigue sin dejar lanzar la aplicación. Alguien sabe el motivo???

Comment: Nadie sabe cómo lanzar whatsapp desde Xamarin.Forms ????